# Reaction-diffusion equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> > Consider the following system of reaction-diffusion equations:
> >     $$
> > u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)-w,~~~~~~w_t=\epsilon (u-\gamma w).~~~~(*)
> > $$
> >     The function $f(u)=u(u-a)(1-u)$ is a cubic, where $a<1/2$. The constants $\epsilon$ and $\gamma$ are positive.

Now, a travelling wave for $(*)$ is a solution that is a function of the single variable $\xi=x-ct$, i.e. $(u(\xi),w(\xi))$ satisfies
$$
-cu_{\xi}=u_{\xi\xi}+f(u)-w,~~~~~-cw_{\xi}=\epsilon (u-\gamma w).
$$

(1) Why is this called travelling wave?

Moreover, it is said, if we recast $(*)$ in a moving coordinate frame, i.e., in terms of variables $\xi=x-ct$ and $t$, we get
$$
u_t=u_{\xi\xi}+c u_{\xi}+f(u)-w,~~~~~w_{t}=cw_{\xi}+\epsilon (u-\gamma w)~~~~~(**)
$$
and the travelling wave is an equilibrium (time independent) solution of $(**)$.

(2) How do we get $(**)$? Did not understand that.

(3) Why is the travelling wave an equilibrium of $(**)$?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Take a function, say $f(\xi)=e^{-\xi^2}$ and make plots of $f(x-ct)$ for, say, $c=1$ and $t=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

(2) Take the equation for the traveling wave solution and eqal it to the derivative with respect to time.

(3) Because the equilibrium of $u_t=Au$, where $A$ some differential (can be nonlinear) operator is $Au=0$.